# How to find the values that make this interval enclose an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Suppose I have an interval that looks like this:

$\left[\frac{k}{\lfloor m \rfloor }, \frac{k}{\lfloor mr \rfloor}\right)$

$m$ and $r$ are positive real numbers, but are constants in this problem.

Here is the question:

Which integer values of $k$ make this interval include at least one integer?

I have tried various ways to tackle this problem, but none have panned out.  The thing is I have no idea where to even start.  How does one solve problems like this?

Comment: Is there any reason to write $mr$ instead of a single constant such as $s$ ?

Comment: Can we assume anything about the values of $m$ and $r$?  If for instance $r\ge 1$, the interval is empty.

Comment: Some people use the definition $[a,b)=(b,a]$ if $a<b$, so in that case, this interval is only empty if $r=1$.

Comment: @vrugtehagel Interesting. I had never heard of this convention.

Comment: And more, is there any reason to use the floor of a real constant where an integer constant can do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the enclosed integer. Assuming $p=\lfloor m\rfloor>q=\lfloor mr\rfloor$, we have

$$\frac kp\le n<\frac kq$$ so that

$$nq<k\le np$$ for all positive $n$.

---

These intervals go growing with $n$ and start touching when

$$np>(n+1)q$$ or

$$n(p-q)>q.$$

When this condition is met, every $k>nq$ is a good fit.

Hence

$$k\in(q,p]\cup(2q,2p]\cup(3q,3p]\cup\cdots(nq,\infty)$$ where $n=\left\lceil\dfrac{q+1}{p-q}\right\rceil$.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this graphically. Consider the graphs of the functions
$f(x) = \frac{1}{\lfloor m\rfloor} x$
and $g(x) = \frac{1}{\lfloor mr\rfloor} x$
in a Cartesian plane with horizontal coordinate $x.$
Now consider all of the points with integer coordinates that lie on or above
the graph of $f(x)$ but below the graph of $g(x).$
The set of $k$ you are looking for is the set of $x$ coordinates of all those points.

Clearly, for $k$ large enough that the difference $g(k) - f(k)$ is at least $1,$ the interval 
$\left[\frac{k}{\lfloor m \rfloor }, \frac{k}{\lfloor mr \rfloor}\right)$
contains at least one integer.
You just have to check the  finite number of values of $k$ for which 
$g(k) - f(k) < 1$ in order to find all remaining values of $k$ for which
$\left[\frac{k}{\lfloor m \rfloor }, \frac{k}{\lfloor mr \rfloor}\right)$
contains at least one integer.

Comment: I wonder if this answer would be improved by omitting the graph and just treating the two functions algebraically.