# How to find the places where this interval encloses an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Suppose I have an interval that looks like this:

$\left[\frac{k}{\lfloor m \rfloor }, \frac{kr}{\lfloor mr \rfloor}\right)$

$m$ and $r$ are positive real numbers, but are constants in this problem.

Here is the question:

Which integer values of $k$ make this interval include at least one integer?

Note that this is very similar to the problem I asked this morning [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2195030/how-to-find-the-values-that-make-this-interval-enclose-an-integer), but I actually copied it down from my sheet of paper wrong.  The problem that I am trying to solve here has an additional $r$ in the second term.

I have tried various ways to tackle this problem, but none have panned out.  The thing is I have no idea where to even start.  How does one solve problems like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the constants $m,r$ are actually specified, the set of qualifying $k$-values can be readily found, but with *unknown* constants $m,r$, it doesn't look like an easy problem.

However, for the existence of a qualifying $k$-value, there are some easy necessary conditions, as well as an easy sufficient condition . .  .

First, some necessary conditions:

We must have

$$m \ge 1\tag{1}$$

$$mr \ge 1\tag{2}$$

to ensure that both endpoints of the interval are defined.

Also, the left endpoint of the interval must be less than the right endpoint, hence

$$\frac{k}{\lfloor{m}\rfloor} < \frac{kr}{\lfloor{mr}\rfloor}$$

Dividing both sides by $k$, yields the necessary condition

$$\lfloor{mr}\rfloor < \lfloor{m}\rfloor{r}\tag{3}$$

Next, a sufficient condition:

If the right endpoint is at least 1 more than the left endpoint, then the interval is guaranteed to contain an integer, hence it will suffice to have

$$\frac{kr}{\lfloor{mr}\rfloor} - \frac{k}{\lfloor m \rfloor} \ge 1$$

which yields the sufficient condition

$$k \ge 
\frac
{{\lfloor{m}\rfloor}{\lfloor{mr}\rfloor}}
{{\lfloor{m}\rfloor{r}}-{\lfloor{mr}\rfloor}}
\tag{4}
$$

Thus, for any choice of constants $m,r$ satisfying the necessary conditions, any value of $k$ greater or equal to

$$
\left
\lceil
{
\frac
{{\lfloor{m}\rfloor}{\lfloor{mr}\rfloor}}
{{\lfloor{m}\rfloor{r}}-{\lfloor{mr}\rfloor}}
}
\right
\rceil
$$

will be a qualifying $k$-value.

However, it's possible for a value of $k$ to be qualifying even if condition $(4)$ is not satisfied. For example, if

$$k=8,\;\;m=\frac{7}{2},\;\;r=\frac{11}{14}$$

then the integer $k=8$ yields the interval

$$\left[\frac{8}{3},\frac{22}{7}\right)$$

which contains the integer $3$, hence for the constants $m,r$ specified above, $8$ is a qualifying $k$-value, even though condition $(4)$ is not satisfied.

Other than the necessary conditions $(1),(2),(3)$, and the sufficient condition $(4)$, I don't know how much more can be said without more information about the constants $m,r$.

For example, suppose $r$ is required to be a positive integer.

Let $s = \lfloor{m}\rfloor$. Then

\begin{align*}
&s = \lfloor{m}\rfloor\\[4pt]
\implies\; &s \le m\\[4pt]
\implies\; &sr \le mr\\[4pt]
\implies\; &\lfloor{sr}\rfloor \le \lfloor{mr}\rfloor\\[4pt]
\implies\; &sr \le \lfloor{mr}\rfloor\qquad\text{[since $s,r$ are integers]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &\lfloor{m}\rfloor r \le \lfloor{mr}\rfloor\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

contrary to necessary condition $(3)$.

Hence, if $r$ is required to be a positive integer, the interval is empty, so there are no qualifying values of $k$.

Comment: If it helps, $r$ will always be a positive integer

Comment: @DarthRubik: If $r$ is a positive integer, there are no qualifying values of $k$. I updated my answer to address  that case.